# How to use magento 2 rest api in react js

Tags: magento2, rest-api, react

I am learning react js with magento. I want to use magento rest api in my react js app how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

In your React component call a fetch request like below:

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
 fetch("http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/categories")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((json) => console.log(json));

 return <div className="App">{}</div>;
}

export default App;
```